# Heatmap with points at specified coordinates

Tags: python, image, plot, coordinates, heatmap

I have a matrix with values and corresponding coordinates and want to draw a heatmap of this matrix for the given coordinates. A working example would be

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

intensities=[[1,3,5],[2,4,6]]

coords=[[[0,0],[1,0],[2,4]],[[2,1],[3,5],[6,1]]]

plt.pcolormesh(intensities)
```

However, I would like the points to be plotted at the coordinates given by coords. Unfortunately, the coordinates cannot be expressed as just two arrays.

I can see that it is likely that pcolormesh and similar are the wrong tool for the job since they fill with rectangles. I do not care about the particular shape of the polygons used to fill the space since I will have sufficiently many points that the effect would not be visible.

The problem arises from trying to postprocess an image. A figure was drawn as corresponding to a non-orthogonal reference frame and I wish to see what it would have looked like had the reference frame been orthogonal.

Comment: How do the `intensities` correspond to the `coords`. And did you intend to defined `coords` as a list of 4 sublists of length 2, as in `coords = [[0,0],[1,0],[2,1],[3,5]]`? (In the OP there appear to be too many brackets around the first two sublists...)

Comment: Apologies, I corrected this now. It is meant that coords[a,b,:] gives the x,y-coordinates of intensities[a,b]. I can also find other ways to write these if that is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Per the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36873933/heatmap-with-points-at-specified-coordinates?noredirect=1#comment61315903_36873933), `coords[a, b,:]` gives the x,y coordinates associated with `intensities[a, b]` for all valid `a`, `b`. So we can pick off the `x`,`y` coordinates with

```
x = coords[..., 0].ravel()
y = coords[..., 1].ravel()
```

and the corresponding color would be given by

```
c = intensities.ravel()
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

intensities = np.array([[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]])
coords = np.array([[[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 4]], [[2, 1], [3, 5], [6, 1]]])

x = coords[..., 0].ravel()
y = coords[..., 1].ravel()
c = intensities.ravel()
plt.scatter(x, y, c=c, s=200)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

`s=200` controls the size of the dots. I used a big value to make the few dots in the example more noticeable. You'll of course want a smaller number if you have lots of points.

Comment: This answers it, if I make the points small enough in my actual plot it shows precisely what I want.